# Doing Relationships in Database CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I currently have a method to post new data into database and it works great, the problems comes when I try to add the current id to the ci_relationship table.

This is my method:

```
public function add()
{
    // Field Rules
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'trim|required|min_length[3]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('status', 'Status', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('is_featured', 'Feature', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('is_commented', 'Comments', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('order', 'Order', 'integer');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        // Select Categories    
        $categories_options = array();
        $categories_options[0] = 'Select Categories';

        $categories_list = $this->Terms_model->get_list();

        foreach($categories_list as $cat){
            $categories_options[$cat->term_id] = $cat->title;
        }

        $data['categories_options'] = $categories_options;

        // Select Post Author ID and Name
        $user_options = array();
        $user_options[0] = 'Select Username ID';

        $user_list = $this->User_model->get_list();

        foreach($user_list as $username){
            $user_options[$username->id] = $username->username;
        }

        $data['user_options'] = $user_options;

        // Load template
        $this->template->load('admin', 'default', 'posts/add', $data);
    } else {
        $slug = str_replace(' ', '-', $this->input->post('title'));
        $slug = strtolower($slug);

        // Upload Image
        $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/img/posts/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE;
        $config['max_size'] = '2048';
        $config['max_width'] = '2000';
        $config['max_height'] = '2000';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        $this->upload->initialize($config);


        $file_name = 'post_image';

        if(!$this->upload->do_upload($file_name)){
            varDebug($this->upload->display_errors());
            $file_name = 'assets/img/noimage.jpg';
        } else {
            $post_image =  $this->upload->data('file_name');
        }

        // Page Data
        $data = array(
            'user_id'       => $this->input->post('user_id'),
            'slug'          => $slug,
            'title'         => $this->input->post('title'),
            'post_image'    => $post_image,
            'body'          => $this->input->post('body'),
            'status'        => $this->input->post('status'),
            'is_featured'   => $this->input->post('is_featured'),
            'is_commented'  => $this->input->post('is_commented'),
            'order'         => $this->input->post('order'),
            'type'          => 'post',
        );

        // Insert Page
        $this->Post_model->add($data);

        $post_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        // Activity Array
        $data = array(
            'resource_id' => $post_id,
            'type'        => 'post',
            'action'      => 'added',
            'user_id'     => $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
            'message'     => 'A new post was added (' . $data["title"] . ')'
        );

        // Insert Activity
        $this->Activity_model->add($data);

        // Insert Categories into CI_TERMS_TAXONOMY - term_taxonomy_id, term_id, type, body, parent_id, count
        $categories = $this->Terms_model->get_list();
        foreach ($categories as $cat) {
            $data = array(
                'term_taxonomy_id'  => $this->db->insert_id(),
                'term_id'           => $cat->term_id,
                'type'              => 'category',
            );
        }

        $this->Taxonomy_model->add($data);


        // Insert Categories into CI_TERMS_RELATIONSHIP - post_id, term_taxonomy_id, term_order
        $taxonomies = $this->Taxonomy_model->get_list();

        $data = array();

        foreach ($taxonomies as $taxonomy){
            $data[] = array(
                'post_id'           => $post_id,
                'term_taxonomy_id'  => $taxonomy->term_taxonomy_id,
            );
        }

        $this->db->insert_batch('ci_terms_relationship', $data);

        // Set Message
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Post has been added');

        // Redirect
        redirect('admin/posts');
    }
}
```

Everything works well in most of the code, I mean I can insert the post into its table, then I add the categories into the ci_taxonomy table and works fine.The problem comes when I try to add the current id to the post_id in the CI_relationship table.

Right now it only trows me this error:

> Duplicate entry '0-1' for key 'PRIMARY'
>
> INSERT INTO 'ci_terms_relationship' ('post_id', 'term_taxonomy_id')
>   VALUES (0,'1'), (0,'2'), (0,'3'), (0,'4'), (0,'5'), (0,'6'), (0,'7'),
>   (0,'8'), (0,'9')

and as it says , it is cause because I have not set up the post_id column as autoincrement but if I do change it, it will not be possible to pass the current id of the post that has been just added to the database... anyone knows any way to fix this, or any tip?

I hope I could make myyself clear on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question: If you get an error "duplicate entry" it means you try to make an INSERT on something existing. You might actually want an UPDATE instead, could that be the reason?

Comment: @Kevin, have you noticed that your post_id is 0? One suggestion, instead of using $this->db->insert_id() in your controller, which is dangerous, have the model functions return the id instead and use the return value.

Comment: Hey @TimBrownlaw , sorry for the late answer but I actually just passed the `$this->db->insert_id()` as a variable, and it started to give me the results that I wanted.... check my updated version.

Comment: hey, @Vickel sorry for the confusion, I was not even sure if somebody was going to even understand the question(I really did not take the effort as I was in a hurry in real life stuff) which just made me write some paragraphs without thinking about it... again, sorry for the confusion.... and no, I was not trying to update.

Comment: @kevin I was talking more about having the model method return the id. Id > 0 on success, id=0 on failure. So $post_id = $this->Post_model->add($data); where $this->db->insert_id(); is returned on success and 0 on failure. Keep the DB stuff inside the model method itself.

Comment: something like this?(this is my add method on model)
`
public function add($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert($this->table, $data);
   
  if($this->db->insert_id() > 0){
   return $this->db->insert_id();
  } else {
   return false;
  }
    }
`

Comment: @kevin that's better... does that make more sense?